# How can I record a 32-bit key in the registry on a 64-bit machine using WiX?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I have this key:

```xml
<Package
    InstallerVersion="200"
    Compressed="yes"
    SummaryCodepage="1251"
    Platform="x64"
    InstallScope="perMachine"/>

<Component Id="RegistryEntries1" Guid="*">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                 Key="Software\SolidWorks\Addins\{GUID-PLACEHOLDER}"
                 Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
        <RegistryValue Type="integer" Value="0"/>
        <RegistryValue Name="Description" Value="SomeText" Type="string"/>
        <RegistryValue Name="Title" Value="ProductName" Type="string"/>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

This key needs to be written in the 32-bit registry section, even if the Windows edition is 64-bit. How can I do this?

Comment: If I change platform to "x86" and run installer on 64 bit mashine, reg key anyway putting in wow64.

Comment: Try setting Win64="no" in the component. Then it will be 32-bit, which is what you want. The component bitness may be defaulting to the bitness of the package.

Comment: This option is not working.

Comment: I think you must be doing something wrong. I have x64 packages that write to the WoW6432 registry item in exactly this way. Perhaps you should post a complete failing WiX source test case, and be sure to look in the right place, in the WoW6432 node for the x86 entries. Also take a log to check that the component is actually being installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PhilDW correctly pointed out, your installation package platform is targeting the x64 but your registry key is being created in the `Wow6432Node`. This node is a source of confusion for me, so here is its definition:

> The Wow6432Node registry entry indicates that you are running a 64-bit Windows version. The operating system uses this key to display a separate view of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE for 32-bit applications that run on 64-bit Windows versions.

Since the registry key is being created in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SolidWorks\Addins\`, it means it's 32-bit. If you want to explicitly create it for 64-bit, add the `Win64="yes"` attribute to the `Component`.

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntries1" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                 Key="Software\SolidWorks\Addins\{GUID-PLACEHOLDER}"
                 Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
        ...
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```